# When should I control background image change with CSS vs Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is more of a general practice question that a problem specific one but I'll give an example of what I mean. There are a lot of things you can control with CSS that you can also do with Javascript, but is one better to lean on than the other?

Example: 
I have four buttons in a nav that are given a class of "selected" when the section they're associated with is in view. So I could either write a CSS statement for each button (or have Sass do it for me with a mixin)

```
#home-butt.selected{
background-image: url(images/home-up.png);}

#about-butt.selected{
background-image: url(images/about-up.png);}

#work-butt.selected{
background-image: url(images/work-up.png);}

#contact-butt.selected{
background-image: url(images/contact-up.png);}
```

Orrr I could write something in javascript to do the same thing. (*I gave the images a title attribute that matched the image name so it could pull from there).

```
title = $(this).attr('title');
$(this).find('img').css("background-image", 
"url(" + 'images/' + (title) + '-up.png' + ")");
```

So my question is which is better to use? Is it the javascript because it's less lines of code? Or the CSS incase javascript is disabled? Or is this a very situational question where there isn't always a right or wrong answer?

Opinions and rebuttals are welcome!

Comment: Do javascript only when you want change something dynamicaly (and also when it can't be done with :hover selector in css).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many cases where **Javascript** developing makes what I'm trying to accomplish much more easy and other cases where **CSS** does that to.

" In the end each "language" has its appropriate place in web development and used wisely can enhance both development and user experience. Learn what those uses are (I recommend experience learning) and apply wisely. In my experience, set in stone rules such as *"Never use JS when a CSS solution exists"* (paraphrased) are rarely best in the practical world. "

If you are working with layout, use **CSS**, if your creating the look and feel use **CSS**, if your doing animations use **CSS3**

If you attach event handlers or reacting to user input use **JavaScript**.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question about "is one better to lean on than the other?"

Keep in mind, that CSS has a specific purpose. To apply the *look* to your application.  JavaScript on the otherhand, is mostly the *feel* of your app.  **Always** prefer CSS over JavaScript when editing styles.

The only time that you ever *should* modify styles using JavaScript is when you have a dynamic application, and need to change styles based on some unknown variable.  Even then, a lot can be achieved with just using CSS.

Also keep in mind that you are using jQuery.  think about jQuery's constructor. it is a CSS selector.

With the concept of CSS pseudo-classes introduced, there is very little that you cannot achieve style-wise with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you want to use CSS, because it's much faster than javascript. Also there are going to be users with javascript disabled, which aren't going to see your enhanced presentation if it relied on js function.

Answer (score 1):

The usual answer is, use CSS when you can, because it will work with JavaScript disabled, and also because you don't have to deal with issues like waiting for elements being available in the DOM before referencing them.

But sometimes it depends. Keep in mind that:

- Depending on the selector or properties you're changing you may have issues with browser compatibility.
- If you're changing the image like in your example, you may see it flicker while the new image is loaded. You can avoid that by using a sprite image, or preloading the images with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule of thumb, I would use CSS for styling and JavaScript only to "make the page alive".

So the best and the most ideal use of JavaScript is to add and remove classes from elements 
- classes, which your CSS is depend on.

Answer (score 0):

Loading the `jQuery` library to perform this simple task is unnecessary and relying on javascript to apply background images to your img tags is unnecessary as well.

If it can be done properly in CSS, and work in all browsers, then it should be done in CSS.

Javascript is for more advanced or complex tasks, which require interaction or animations that CSS can't provide for all browsers (due to cross browser compatibility issues - check out caniuse.com)

In your example, if the `.selected` attribute is being given dynamically by javascript for instance:

```
makeSelected(elm)
{
document.getElementById(elm).className='selected';
}
```

then i would still personally add the styling for `.selected` in CSS instead of adding the image through javascript.

If you're adding `.selected` based on the current page you're on and not through javascript then I would recommend using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer CSS over Script for one main reason **Browser compatibility**

There are just soooo many times when one script code or the other isn't compatible in one browser or the other (*cough* or just IE)

With css I haven't had such issues yet (*touchwood*) and also if there were any issues CSS's won't affect as much as script's which just don't let any other following codes to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Let me provide my opinion.

Personally I don't believe a website should have a lot of "*gimmicks*" in terms of designing.
BY gimmicks I mean hovering effects, music in the background(absolute no-no) or other "eye-catching details". All of this looks good the first time but subsequently visitors get fed up with this distractions.

Without deviating from the main issue. **CSS/JavaScript** for styling.

Well they do exist hand in hand. The best example for this would be **Bootstrap** library. Although I have never used it personally but it seems amazing what can be achieved using CSS and JavaScript.

So, We will need both to design spectacular website. CSS helps in the basic designing and to make the website more *responsive* we use JavaScript and its derivative libraries like Jquery for all the finer looking stuff